# How to determine which input field was populated on JSP?

Tags: java, string, jsp, input, struts2

have Struts project and web-form based JSP page with several input fields. Users enters data to the ONLY one input field and submit the form. So the related Action class is called. 
In that action-class I have proper String fields for every input on JSP and later in my code I need to use populated value to find some data.

So my question is:
how would you determine which field was populated?

'cause I know the only one stupid way (not real code, just as an example):

```
if (isNotBlank(field_1)) {
findData(field_1)
} else if (isNotBlank(field_2)) {
findData(field_2)
} else if (isNotBlank(field_3)) {
findData(field_3)
} else if...
```

and so on...
Is there any elegant way for group of strings to determine which one is not blank?
any hints are appreciated. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general approaches to your problem. The first approach, which I think may be the best, is to refactor your user interface. Instead of presenting a slew of input fields, ask the user which input field she will be using, then prompt her with only that field. To do this well, I'd suggest some javascript that manipulates how the form is submitted. The pseudo-code in the struts action would look like:

```
findData( whichInput( firstQuestion ) )
```

From there, you are attempting to decide which field to use based the user's answer to the first question. If you consider that the first question could simply result in an index, and you place the inputs for the second question in a List rather than independently declared variables, you could further simplify to -

```
findData( fields.get( whichInput.intValue() ) )
```

In this case, your action would be greatly simplified because the "fields" list will have a single getter / setter and the "whichInput" property can be declared as an Integer.

This leads me to the second approach which is likely to be easier to incorporate to your existing user interface. Much like the first approach I described, Change from having field_1, field_2... field_n to having a single List variable, called fields. Then, in your user interface, use indexes like

```
<s:input name="fields[1]" label="Field 1" value="%{fields[1]}" />
```

From your action code, you can then loop over the fields rather than having a large if/else block:

```
for (String field : fields) {
    if (isNotBlank( field ) ) {
        findData( field );
    }
}
```